# 2D segment tree query time complexity

Tags: data-structures, runtime-analysis, search-trees

These sources [cp-algorithms](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html) and [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-dimensional-segment-tree-sub-matrix-sum/)
state that query complexity (for example, submatrix sum) of 2-D segment tree is O(logN * logM), because

> it first descends the tree in the first coordinate, and for each traversed vertex of that tree, it makes a query from the usual tree of segments along the second coordinate

However, in all implementations I have met, a query descends the tree along the second coordinate  only when it reaches some node of the first tree  (cannot recurse any further). Next, since there are no more than 4 recursive calls per level of a segment tree during a query, there would be no more than 4 queries along the second coordinate in total. So, in my view, the rime complexity should be O(logN **+** logM). What do I miss?

Comment: What do you mean by 4 recursive calls per level? The number of levels is log M so you need, for each row in question, to do log M work, no?

Comment: https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html contains a proof that during a query at each level  no more than four vertices is visited

Comment: I think in your case I would implement the algorithm you have in mind and try to prove the running time you believe is right. Either you have a proof, or you reach an insight.